# disable aero visual styles on a wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, aero

how to disable aero visual style on a wpf application in windows 7/Vista. The preferred method of approach is in the order of preference.
1) Application manifest
2) PINVOKE calls

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I came across SetThemeAppProperties. msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759825(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

My solution involved creating a template for the Window.

First of all, set `WindowStyle = None` and `ResizeMode = NoResize` with these both properties you'll have a borderless window like this one (Opacity set to 50%):

[image: a borderless window]

In VS Designer, right click your Window `Edit Template -> Edit a copy...`. Now, this is the difficult part. Check for the code below:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
         <AdornerDecorator>
             <ContentPresenter/>
         </AdornerDecorator>
       </Border>
  </ControlTemplate>
```

I got rid of the `Border` and `AdornerDecorator`, but it's not necessary.
Wrap your `ContentPresenter` inside a `Grid` with 3 rows and 3 columns at position 1,1:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition/>
       <RowDefinition/>
       <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition/>
       <ColumnDefinition/>
       <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

For the other locations, just insert `Rectangles` as your borders.
Unfortunately, I don't have the Code behind with me right now, but if you search for "WPF Resize window", you'll find easily.

I know it is a "hack", but it works :)

EDIT: [Here's a link with the Code Behind](http://blog.kirupa.com/?p=256)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to render your own chrome for the window. There's even the [Microsoft.Windows.Shell library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.windows.shell.windowchrome%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which will do most of the hard work for you.

And if you want to avoid all of the work, then take a look at [WinChrome.Codeplex.com](https://winchrome.codeplex.com/) for some styles that I've put together.

[image: VS2012 like]

Also if you want more detail, I've covered a fair bit of the explanation behind it in [Recreating Office2013/VS2012 window glow](http://alski.net/post/2013/09/14/WPF-Re-creating-VS2012Office-2013-window-glow.aspx).